# Using Coalesce in Where Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a query here and I'm curious if there is a shorter way of writing this query, meaning to reduce the query from using an `IF` argument to determine if it should use the param or not in the statement.  Please see below:

```
 @Param varchar(10) = NULL

 IF @Param IS NOT NULL
   BEGIN
     SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE Column = @Param
   END
 ELSE
   BEGIN
     SELECT * FROM TABLE
   END
```

Could this be reduced to one simple query instead like this?

```
 @Param varchar(10) = NULL

 SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE Column = COALESCE( Any, @Param )
```

I looked at `Coalesce`, but didn't see if I could use an `Any` sort of feature. I hope this makes sense.

Question is how to acheive this.  Second question is which would be better on performance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no `any` style command, but if you use the `@Param` first and then the value in the column itself, that should work...

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE Column = COALESCE(@Param, Column)
```

If `@Param` is Null then it is ignored and the next item in the list is used.

You can also use `IsNull` to do the same thing...

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE Column = ISNULL(@Param, Column)
```

---

To answer the 2nd part of the question, my feeling is that using a separate statement will always be more efficient.  The condensed version might be less code, but isn't necessarily easier to understand or quicker to run.

Comment: Thanks, do those practically do the same thing?  Also, which out of your two examples and my first one, is better on performance do you think?

Comment: Yes, the do exactly the same thing. I cannot say which would be the most efficient between the two... but my feeling is that separate statements will always be more efficient

Comment: @ZeeTee - ISNULL performs quite a lot better in some circumstances, and I have *never* seen COALESCE perform better for a two-parameter usage.

Comment: Thanks for your input @Matt, I can very much believe that, but I did not have the facts to make the claim myself